# linux .so windows .dll - using different librarys "on demand"

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I have a collection of so files on linux, e.g.: netio.so.tcp and netio.so.tcp.
(in fact this architecture is only needed because of some proprietary network protocols)
They have the exactly same interface for read/write/open/close.
So to use tcp or udp i just create a symlink from either one of these libs to netio.so which my application is linked against. Works fine.

The same application has to run on windows too, but here i can't seem to change names of the dlls.
Is there some standard way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since softlinks on windows differ in some things(only admin can create them) and don't exist on win versions prior to vista, I implemented it using explicit linking.
win:
LoadLibraryA/GetProcAddress
linux:
dlopen/dlsym